# Actual use of index in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have created an index as

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON TABLE1(id);
```

and I have read about index as they are used to increase the performance of retrieval from the database. How can I check that and using what type of query ? Does it go something like

```
SELECT id FROM index1 USE INDEX(index1);
```

Please give me the right syntax of using the select statement with index.I tried with many sites but I got only the above query. Thanks.

Comment: The optimizer will decide when it makes sense to use the index. In general  you shouldn't tell the optimizer what to do. If you really know what you are doing you can [use a hint](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF00219) to suggest to the optimizer that the index might make sense. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) to verify the index usage. You seem to be new with Oracle, so my recommendation is: let the optimizer do the job, don't mess around with hints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So you are saying that even when I query using a normal select query like 'SELECT id from TABLE1' the optimizer will automatically use the index (if available) to retrieve the values ?

Comment: It will use the index if it makes the query faster, not just because it's there. You might want to read: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thanks dude. You are right I am just learning sql and this web site will help me a lot in understanding the internal process that is happening when we qurey a table.